# Linking high poly to low poly rigged mesh

Tags: rigging

[image]
Needless to say - I'm REALLY new to blender.
How do I link these two models?
I have the low poly one posed but I have no idea where to start to 'swap' it for the non-rigged high poly model.
I appended both models to my tracked scene, but they are from two separate files.

Comment: what do you mean by link and by swap these 2 models? If you want to transfer the vertex groups from the low-poly to the high-poly, maybe look into the Data Transfer modifier? But generally it's better not to animate a high-poly, instead you should bake its normals in order to give the low-poly "fake" 3D details...

Comment: Again I have no idea about the low poly vs high poly workflow. So instead of adding a rig to high poly mesh, I should bake details from the high poly one? Keep in mind it's got different textures etc.

Comment: Unless your high-poly is not too high in poly, the most common thing is to work all the 3D details on a high-poly, then bake them into a normal map, and use this normal map to give fake 3D details to the low-poly. This way you only use and animate the low-poly, which is much more convenient because it needs much less render and animation calculations. So if that's what you want to do you don't need to rig the high-poly, you just need to align the low-poly pose to the high-poly and learn how to bake

Comment: So what is the point of having the low poly model with non-baked detail in a separate file? I don't really undestand that part. Why wouldn't it have already all the details baked?

Comment: I don't know anything about what is your project, how you got these objects, what you are supposed to do with them, etc, so I can't answer, I can only tell what are the common practices, maybe ask to the person who has created it? Also check the low-poly materials to see if it doesn't already have a normal map?

Comment: Actually there is a normal map - maybe I'll play around with it, thank you for your help.